# Answering "why do you leave your job ?" when the reason is the better salary?

Tags: interviewing

I just joined my current company in 6 months, but now I feel unhappy with the salary here. So I want to find another job for higher salary, what should I say if the interviewer ask me "why do you leave your job ?". Should I say that I want a higher salary ? If you were interviewer then what do you think about me after my answer ?

Comment: Strongly related question: [Answering why do you want to join our company when the sole reason is good income and better benefits?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/12659/1193)

Comment: If the salary was too low why did you join them 6 months ago?

Comment: You can always say that your are looking for better opportunities for growth or something of this sort.

Comment: @corsiKa: Because a low salary is a lot better than no salary at all?

Comment: Take @JoeStrazzere comment, and hopefully what happened in the last 6 months is that you gained lots of experience, you found that you were much better than others at what you were doing and so on. If he asked the question in an interview and you gave a good answer, that would really strengthen your position

Comment: "The job was not what I expected/was promised/whatever, and that is important to me."

Answer (score 3):

Usually you go with something like this "I was thinking that I was going for a position with more responsibility, but it turned out not to be that way. I was disillusioned." In and of itself, more responsibility, comes with more money. When it is time to discuss salary, you can say you expect this much for more responsibility etc.

If you bring it flat out saying "I want more money" I can almost guarantee, it will not go well.

Answer (score 1):

It is always about presentation. Everyone wants more salary. It is how you say it. If you say that , you will have a lower rank in the number of people who have answered the question. But if you said , "I am looking for more challenges", then it is not so blatant and more tactful. the interviewer is looking for more tact than real answer. I have given you a general idea so go prepare your own answer.

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to include some quoted text in your answer?