# Why you looking out for change?

Tags: interviewing, job-change

I am working in Software development and have recently faced couple of interviews.

**Interview 1:**
I have cleared the first (Technical) round, when I faced the HR round, the first question they have asked me is "Why you looking out for change?".

I answered with better prospects in terms of salary and carrier growth. The next question is HR asked is "Are you not getting any growth in current organization?"

I was stuck at that question.

**Interview 2:**
I have faced an HR discussion and again I have been asked the same one.

How do I answer this question without any imperfection and what possibly the best way to answer it?

And if they ask any further like “why you do not have growth here?” or “if you have growth in current organization, then why look out another one?”

checked this so [question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/6475/how-to-respond-to-why-are-you-looking-for-a-new-job), but unable to get the exact answer.

Comment: downvoters cares to comment

Comment: I have not downvoted but I would say it's because its the exact same as the linked question.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I must say, in terms of technology as well as money. but i Hesitated all the time to make these points(specially money) as the reason of change.

Comment: @asdasd why?  I mean, you're unhappy with where you are.  There must be a reason, and as long as it isn't some silly, petty thing (the colors of the walls were too blue) or due to some sort of major screw up on your part, you should be fine with being honest.  If you're looking for more growth with a new company, OBVIOUSLY you're not getting enough from your current company.  They ask in order to clarify your answer, and to try and find out if they can offer you more opportunities than you currently have.

Comment: This question may be qualitatively different.  In the other example the person wasn't looking for a change, he was solicited out of the blue.  This one appears to be motivated by dissatisfaction with a current position.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to be careful when answering this interview question. Your response can make the difference between getting the job or not. This question can be asked in several different ways including, "Why do you want to leave your present job?" or, "Why aren't you content with your present position?" An interviewer may also ask you this same question with respect to past positions. However they phrase this question, keep your responses positive and focus more on the open position.

**More Challenging Assignments**

One reason you can state that you are looking for a new job is more challenging assignments. Start by saying something positive about your present job. You must know about the new position to make such a comment, so always obtain a full copy of the job description before your interview. Another option is to tell the interviewer how excited you are about the position and challenges that await you.

**More Security**

Greater job security is another acceptable response to any question about leaving your current job. Explain why you feel security would be greater with the open position. You may work for a small upstart company and want more security with a bigger firm. Tell the interviewer how you liked the experience you gained on your job. Larger companies usually offer better benefits, including college tuition reimbursement, so this is a acceptable response.

**More Money**

More money can be an appropriate reason for leaving a job. However, you must already know the salary range of the new position before using this response. Salaries are sometimes listed in job descriptions or online job ads. Whatever the case, explain how you enjoyed your previous job but felt somewhat underpaid. This may be obvious to the interviewer if you volunteer your salary. Most human resources managers know average salaries for jobs because they research salary data.

**Location**

Companies relocate employees around all the time. Consequently, you may not like where you live. You may also have too far to commute to work. This is common in larger cities that are widespread, where homes in outlying areas are cheaper and located in more desirable suburbs.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is simply a case of choosing your words carefully.
But the obvious answer would be: "In my current job I do not have the growth possibilities that best suit my interests."
You can elaborate on this, continue saying what you would want in a growth path.

Answer (score 1):

> "Are you not getting any growth in current organization?"
>
> How do I answer this question without any imperfection and what possibly the best way to answer it?

There is no correct answer to this question. There is the truth. And there are bad answers.

You are looking for a job, they tried to determine why you are looking. It can tell them how serious is your search, and how likely you are to stay if they offer you a job.

When they asked why you are leaving you said X (salary) and y (career growth). They took one of your answers and asked you to explain it.

So before your next interview think of 2 or three examples to explain your reason. Pretend you are telling a parent or good friend. Then clean it up to sound like an answer you will give at an interview. Avoid trivial examples, and make sure it isn't a rant.

If it turns out that career growth isn't one of the reasons for leaving, then go through the same process for that reason.

Why do they care? If they can't meet your needs you might not stay around for long. If you can't explain why you are looking, you might not be a serious candidate.

Answer (score 0):

There are reasons that you are applying for that particular job.  Something made it stand out so tell them what it was.  If it is a development technology they listed you can say that you think technology A, B, or C will benefit your career.  If the company is multinational and you have aspirations in that area tell the interviewer so.  If you admire the company or have used their products and/or believe in their future prospects now would be a time to speak up.  I applied to positions for reasons such as:

- "my present company is relocating our division to China."
- "My parents have recently taken ill and this will provide me an opportunity to care for them."
- "My current organization is very top heavy and I
  don't see any movement possible for quite some time."

It is very important to never complain about your employer, supervisor, or co-workers.

Answer (score -2):

> Why you looking out for change?

The answer to the question totally depends on the particular case. **Just answer the truth.** I believe you actually know why you are looking out for change. There could be a lot of appropriate answers. And I hope the actual reason it's not a kind of information that can raise some red flags over you. Indeed if it is so you are not in a good situation. Either you lie something appropriate (which I do **NOT** recommend you to do) or you probably may not be hired. It is you to decide what to do according to your moral code.

For me for example the main part of the answer would be, because of a terrible working environment. At the moment I am working in an open-space with 100 people who constantly talk to each other and over the phones. The noise level is so high that I always get a headache after a working day. By the way, if they ask me why did I accept that offer I would answer that originally I was working in a nice small office but was forced to move to open space later.

Comment: Please, explain down-vote.

Comment: I am down voting this answer for two reasons. Complaining about a previous employer during a job interview is a bad idea.  Being too honest (my corkers and I don't get along) could also lead to an uncomfortable line of questioning.

Comment: @ojblass It is not a bad idea in my opinion to say that working environment was inappropriate at the time you left. I started working in a small office and then was moved to an open space. This is an understandable and appropriate reason to leave (if I could not be moved to some silent place even if I did ask for it), isn't it?

Comment: @Kolyunya I agree with ojblass. Complaining about the previous place of work may have negative repercussions and cause a variety of issues. Also we try to avoid encouraging users to lie to get ahead.

Comment: @MichaelGrubey what if it is truly the one and the only reason I leave (my particular case)? Do I lie something *appropriate*? No? What shall I do then? Truth is the best policy!

Comment: @Kolyunya Saying it is a terrible working environment is a personal opinion. If you said that reason to me I would be doubting your ability to work with background noise which might limit your ability to work with a large team. Honesty is the best policy so why recommend the OP to lie.

Comment: "Moving to an open floor plan" as the reason for changing jobs means that you are inflexible.  The floor plan configuration is not often listed on the job description.  This will walk you into a bad line of questioning.

Comment: @MichaelGrubey where did I **recomend** to lie? I wrote `Just answer the truth` with bold font and mentioned to lie as one of theoretically available options. For me an open plan would be an immediate deal-breaker. So it's better to state this as soon as possible imo.

Comment: @Kolyunya "Either you lie something appropriate or you may probably to be hired" is advising the OP to lie. Your edit which you put in a mere minute ago(which everyone can see) changes this fact. If you wish to carry this conversation on lets go to chat.

Comment: @MichaelGrubey saying `Either you lie something appropriate or you may not be hired` is NOT an **advise**. It is an **enumeration** of theoretically available options. It would have been an **advise** if I said `I advise you to lie ...`