# Good reason for leaving current job

Tags: interviewing, new-job, resignation, job-change

I work for a very small business and planning to quit soon. The reason being other employees are leaving as well and it's a mess to work there with minimal resources and extra workload on the left over employees. There is no potential for career growth either.

How do I explain this situation on a job interview? Or should I just state 'looking for better opportunities'?

Comment: See also [How should I explain why I left my last job at an interview?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/62649/how-should-i-explain-why-i-left-my-last-job-at-an-interview).

Comment: As long as the reasons are plausible, they don't have to be true. If the reason is true (even if it's not the main reason) all the better.

Comment: @Smock, I would counter your point by saying, it's better to be generic (yet still honest) than to outright lie. You'd be surprised how easy it is to tell when a candidate makes up an answer, especially to that question. You can usually get a good feeling for why they left by how they answer other questions, at any rate - and if those hints don't line up with the answer that give to this question, it erodes their credibility (even if both the "real" reason and the "fake" reason aren't inherently bad).

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of options to describe this.

Exactly as you described it here

'looking for better opportunities'
'no potential for growth'

You can also say that you want to
 'Work more with latest technology' etc

Answer (score 1):

"No potential for growth" is probably your best bet. It's a realistic concern that any employee *should* have. It shows you consider your professional development a priority where some are happy to just middle out with a livable salary. It is a very palatable reason for a recruiter or hiring manager. It addresses the stagnation at your current employer without doing so directly. And best of all, its true.

Answer (score 0):

If asked, just state that you want more challenge, as your current employer is nice to have offered you experience, but you are ready for a bigger adventure.