# Doing excellent in the new job but looking at a transfer

Tags: new-job, internal-transfer, graduate

I have been in my new job since August at a nonprofit organization that serves the homeless population. I am a receptionist. It is hard work but I have several years experience that makes it a pretty smooth position, at least, that is what I thought, until this past month.

My original manager left at the end of September and I REALLY enjoyed her (she was an inspiring leader). I feel a little like things have gone down hill in my department since she left.

Today I heard from one of my managers that they might not have the budget to hire a new manager for me and several other staff members. As much as I like my two bosses, they don't really have time to manage me (I don't need close supervision but also have some concerns that they don't have time to address)

Meanwhile, the organization has a job posting for an administrative assistant within the development department (seemingly worlds away from my current position).

I have gotten nothing but great feed back from my interim managers, so that is not the problem.

I am also a grad student in my last semester and am interested in development and ideally want to do that work going forward.

I have applied for the job.

Is this a bad idea? Also, if I get an interview how should i handle the inevitable  questions like why are you leaving your current post with us, etc?

Comment: Some companies allow and/or encourage internal transfers, so it's not objectively a bad idea, but some might object to it, so we don't really know what your specific company would think about it. [How to respond to "Why are you looking for a new job?"](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/6475) Also related: (all the more because it's the same employer) [Why is it not a good idea to "badmouth" a previous employer?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/42121)

Comment: I would check your company's policy. There are companyies that don't allow voluntary internal transfer for a certain period of time from the date of hire.

Answer (score 2):

> Is this a bad idea?

No. It's completely fine.

> why are you leaving your current post with us

The trick is focusing on the positives.

You enjoy your job, and are doing well at it, but you're graduating soon and you're interested in development as a career.

The admin role came up and you'd like the opportunity to work in that field.

Truthful, positive and gets the point across.

If you're asked what you can bring to the admin role, you'd be surprised at how much cross over there is from your current role.

An admin (usually) needs to be organised, efficient and good at communicating with a wide variety of people. I'm sure you can find examples in your current role where you have demonstrated these qualities.

I wish you the best of luck and hope things work out for you.