# A change in application

Tags: interviewing

Recently applied for a job and have gotten an interview.  At  the time I was applying I was leaving for financial reasons and job growth.  A situation has arisen and I may be fired with cause.  How should I handle this when I go for the interview?

Comment: see also: [Explaining getting fired in job interview?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/17906/explaining-getting-fired-in-job-interview)

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate, since the OP has not yet been fired.  In addition, the question deals with an application that was sent before the potential firing, with the interview itself possibly after (but possibly not).  So while those other questions can be useful, they don't appear to me to be duplicates.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You haven't been fired for cause yet. Until you have been fired for cause, you haven't been fired for cause. Until you have been fired - period, you haven't been fired - period. The info that you put into your application is what happened. Speculation about what could happen has no place on an application. Because speculation is 1: certainly not info; 2: unverifiable. Don't put anything unverifiable in your applications because you'll make the job of your prospective employer's HR that much harder and that much more frustrating. Don't drive them crazy, work with them.

Having said that, if you are actually fired for cause while your application is pending,  you will have to update your prospective employer's HR before they actually start the background check on you. Make sure that you include your own take - one or two sentences - as to what happened, because merely stating that you have been fired for cause is pretty one-sided information.

It is quite possible that your current employer will say that you resigned voluntarily instead of saying that you got fired for cause. Make sure that you pinpoint what your current employer is going to officially say before you say anything. Getting fired for cause is painful. You'll make it more painful on yourself if additionally, your credibility and integrity are being called into question because you chose to include unverifiable speculation in your application.

Comment: This is helpful.  I'm not sure of the outcome of a situation this week.