# Is it OK to say real reason of Laying off to new Recruiter?

Tags: software-industry, job-search, human-resources, layoff

I am working as System Analyst in small scale company but my company lay off many of its employees, including me, because some clients left the company.

Now I have started hunting for jobs, but if recruiters ask me for the reason behind leaving my job then is it OK to say real reason?

Comment: Remember, being laid off does not reflect poorly on you, especially if a lot of other people were laid off at the same time. There is a big difference between being laid off and being fired.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> **Recruiter:** Why did you leave the company? 
>  **You:** I was laid off. The company ran into financial issues. 
>  **Recruiter:** What sort of issues? 
>  **You:** You'd have to ask them. 
>  **Recruiter:** Did they lay off a lot of staff? 
>  **You:** A number. Now if you don't mind let's discuss the position you contacted me about.

Recruiters always want to know **more**. What few people seem to remember is that **"it's none of your business"** is a valid answer.

In this case revealing the truth is not detrimental to you, however avoid going into details. It's a little too much like gossiping.

Comment: but sir it seems little harsh?

Comment: @ChetanChaudhari what's harsh about it? It's not really any of their business, and lying is a lot harsher and just reminding them that it doesn't matter.

Comment: You should always be up front with how many people were laid off *or* that you were the newest / most junior person on the team. Hiring managers might otherwise suspect they cut the fat first. The script you suggest would feel like pulling teeth to me and I'd wonder if the candidate was hiding something. I assume you worded it like that to show that you don't want to go into the former company's business but that's not how it comes across to me.

Comment: @Lilienthal, I think the takeaway is that you should be honest without going into so much detail that isn't necessary.  You may want need the former company's reference, and bad mouthing them isn't going to help.

Comment: @SiXandSeven8ths Sure, but stating facts that are public information without going into details isn't bad mouthing. It's fine to say "They laid off a lot of people." [This](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/44048/how-to-convince-potential-employers-that-i-was-not-laid-off-due-to-poor-performa) covers most of it I think.

Comment: I prefer "I'm sorry, but I wouldn't feel right sharing that" over "It's none of your business."  It is important to show some tact and demonstrate that you won't be a PITA to work with if you get the job.  I'm reminded of that famous quote from the Dude in The Big Lebowski, "You're not wrong Walter.  You're just an asshole."

Comment: "Now if you don't mind..." sounds very much like fake politeness sending the message of "I don't care what you want, I'm done talking about this". You can get the same effect without the negative tone by just *actually* changing the subject instead of stating that you want to change the subject. "Can we talk about..." would be somewhere between those two.

Comment: @ChetanChaudhari The language AndreiROM uses might be more blunt than what I would say, but the overall message still applies. You don't need to hide that you were laid off, especially if a lot of other people got laid off at the same time. It's up to you whether you say the company was struggling financially or not, but you shouldn't be expected to know why you company had the layoffs.

Comment: Thank you very much .hope this will help me in next interview ,many people misguided me to don't say real reason but finally stack workplace help me.

Comment: One thing too few people realize is that recruiters only get paid when someone takes a job, and they get paid by the company. They can be hella helpful if you understand their role, but they do *not* work for you, and will eg: happily spend their time and energy trying to convince you to change or lower your requirements rather than negotiate with the employer for you.

Answer (score -1):

Why not just say that your company had some financial restructuring and your position is no longer in need at the moment?

This should solidify your position and reason as to what happened without giving too much information.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question does it?

Comment: Why wouldn't it? Can you provide your reasons? OP was asking if he can say the real reason to the recruiter and I gave him another option than the first answer (which he already accepted). There's no need to say the real reason. IMO, conveying that his company was restructuring is enough.