# Need help on how to answer the question "have you ever been dimissed or asked to resign in any position?"

Tags: applications

I am curious how you answer the question "have you ever been dimissed or asked to resign in any position?"

The job application I am looking at has a box for a yes or no answer. After, it has a small box to explain.

If the question doesn't specifically ask to state every instance of being dismissed or forced to resign, do I have to include every single time I was let go? Can I just give one example?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Here's a question related to the actual explanation you're asked for: [In a job interview, how do I explain why I was fired?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/17906) Although whether they're expecting one example or all of them is something only they would know (but I can't imagine that trying to explain more than one of them would count in your favour).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In a job interview, how do I explain why I was fired?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/17906/in-a-job-interview-how-do-i-explain-why-i-was-fired)

Answer (score 2):

I would say that "have you been asked to resign" including an explanation is something which I probably would not answer since it would require me to spill beans about my previous employers. It could reveal their HR strategy, and it may disclose a delicate financial situation of my employer.

I could imagine in an interview something along the lines of: "After discussing career options with my boss I came to the conclusion to leave."

Comment: thank you for this comment. This is what I did on the application- I said "yes," explained one incident, and in the interview, the question was never brought up.

Comment: Asked to resign is not the same as being made redundant - you do know that ?