# Fired for misconduct

Tags: termination

I was fired for misconduct for printing an inappropriate cartoon for a co worker who posted it for other employees and customers to see. It was a cartoon of a manager pointing a gun at an employee.

I was a warehouse supervisor and director of the company and got terminated after 15 years.

This job was the best job in the world for me because at 55 with health issues I could physically manage my job. Now its going to be very difficult for me to start over. How do I tell any prospective company about being fired for misconduct.

Comment: This kind of question shows up rather often, here's a good previous answer https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/17907/76299

Comment: So printing it compared to posting it... who was worse??

Comment: Unless you are in a jurisdiction where you can be fired for any/no reason whatsoever, you may want to consider contesting the termination. Being terminated after 15y for a joke without a (written) warning seem excessive. If you're 55 AND have health issues, you could probably even find a lawyer who can try to claim wrongful termination because of one of these reasons (with the cartoon just being a scapegoat) - assuming your coworker wasn't fired as well, since he publicly shared said cartoon...

Answer (score 21):

> How do I tell any prospective employer about being fire for misconduct.

Your best bet when asked is complete honesty.

You did something foolish that you regret. You understand why you were fired. You have learned from the episode and obviously won't repeat it. Other than that you were a terrific worker and would be a valuable asset for any company that hires you.

Only take this path if it is the truth.

Answer (score 1):

I do concur that being honest is a good thing. However, you do not have to outright disclose that you were fired, at least not until asked why or if you have to submit a background check. I would just put on the resume that you worked at such-and-such for 15 years and looking for a new position. At the interview if they ask about your previous position explain the situation honestly. That way you can be in a position to explain yourself rather than being turned down after they read on the resume that you were fired.

Answer (score 1):

Sue or threaten to sue your ex-company for age discrimination and medial discrimination, most lawyers will take this kind of case on contingency so you won't have to pay anything upfront. At the very least this should get the company to let you resign instead of being fired for misconduct.

Even if you signed something agreeing to the misconduct talk to a lawyer about this.

Comment: Nothing the OP said suggests age or medical discrimination. Where do you see that?

Comment: OP is 55, has health issues, and was just fired. Assuming that this is in America it is costly and uncertain for the ex-company to fight a suit against this regardless of the reality of the situation. Thus the ex-company will possibly settle and almost certainly allow OP to resign, which costs them nothing.

Comment: Apparently the OP was a supervisor and a director of the company. That's exactly the type of thing a supervisor/director should know inside out.

Comment: No I don't think knowledge of employment law is something they need to know working in a warehouse even as a supervisor. What OP means by being "director of the company" is unclear, but i assume its not as high level as you are thinking

Comment: @Kabard that information is in the original post by the OP. It may, of course, be a leap to a medical discrimination but IANAL.