# How do i address misconduct in interview?

Tags: interviewing

I was recently let go because of an honest mistake and misunderstanding with my manager. I only meant to compliment my manager but she took it the wrong way. I was shocked and it blew my mind. No matter how honestly i explain this, i can tell that its costing me a job...  how do i explain this in interview and still get a job? Do i say it wasnt a good fit? If future employers were to find out the details or i was let go due to harassment, would i be let go again?

Edit: if i were to answer honestly and let interviewers know, wouldnt they see me as a liability and avoid me at all cost?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In a job interview, how do I explain why I was fired?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/17906/in-a-job-interview-how-do-i-explain-why-i-was-fired)

Comment: Or duplicate of this: https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/2761/how-do-i-explain-getting-fired-for-a-very-bad-reason-to-potential-employers

Comment: Im curious as to what sort of compliment you used that was taken the wrong way. Usually a once of offensive remark isn't enough to warrant a person being fired.

Answer (score 10):

You have to have honestly learned what you did wrong, and how you're not going to do the same in the future.  So when asked in an interview, you can say something like:

> I complimented my boss's dress and was let go for harassment.  I've realized that it's inappropriate to comment on the body of a co-worker, and the way I worded it, it certainly could have been taken as a comment on her body, not her clothing.  It was inappropriate.  I no longer make comments about co-workers, and I am careful to treat all co-workers with the same respect.  In fact, if I want to compliment a co-worker now, I will comment on their work - since that is what we are here for.

In other words: admit you messed up, explain what you learned, and how it's not part of who you are any more.  That is your best approach when you are fired for any reason.

HOWEVER - if you can avoid bringing it up at all, if it doesn't come up, then you simply need to internalize the lesson.  You certainly don't proactively bring up the reason you were fired from a job in an interview.  If it comes up, then you explain why now is different and what you have learned.  If it doesn't come up, don't bring it up.

Comment: I definitely learned my lesson and realized that we live in a sensitive world. Showing that ive learned and reflected is something i am going to let interviewer know, but is theres another way to go about explaining this misconduct? I feel like every interview i had is considering me as a liability.... when in fact i am actually a really hard worker. I just honestly didnt think my manager would take it as offense because she and i would talk casually all the time. This really caught me off guard.

Comment: @Lfhelpxyz You're only a liability if you don't learn.  You have to learn all sorts of things to do your job, this is just one more thing.  Sure, there were consequences because you didn't learn it sooner, but that's also true of other things.  If it comes up in an interview, you have to convince them you've learned and changed.

Comment: I just feel like nobody will ever hire me if i were to go into details. This has crushed my self confidence. I feel like my career is ruined.

Comment: @Lfhelpxyz Crushed confidence can also be a reason for someone to not hire you. Learn from mistakes, but don't wallow in self-pity over having made them. People make mistakes, people regret mistakes, and people move on from mistakes. When discussing it with potential employers, go into exactly as much detail as you must - no extra details, but don't leave anything vital out (since that can make it look like you're hiding things), and *be confident* that you've learned.

Comment: So what do yoy propose i should say? Its hard to explain this without making it sound like a harassment since harassment is something that was done intentionally.

Comment: @Lfhelpxyz actually, harassment doesn't have to be intentional.  In many cases, it's unintentional but also unthinking, not realizing you're treating women (or another category) different from men, because you're not thinking about it from their point of view.  To put it in more concrete terms - if you hit me with your car, but it was unintentional, I am still hurt.

Comment: Right i can see that. Ive reflected a lot and learned that we live in a very sensitive world. I just dont want this to be career ending

Comment: @Lfhelpxyz - unfortunately, as long as you look at it as "we live in a sensitive world", you don't really understand.  I'm not "sensitive" because I was hit by a car.  I'm tired of being hit by a car and having to assure the driver that it's all ok.  You're still not getting outside of yourself, and seeing what it's like having co-workers comment on your body, as a compliment, over and over, and over.  When you really wish the co-worker would quit seeing your body at all and would instead see your work.  It's not "sensitive" to be want to be known as competent and equal.

Comment: @Lfhelpxyz But it does not need to be career ending!

Comment: No believe me i see your point. I wasnt thinking clearing and i gracefully own up to my mistake. My intention was never to cause any harm. I only had the purest intention when i complimented. I wanted to let her know that she was simply pretty. Thats it. If i ever disrespected anyone, i immediately apologise.

Comment: If you're still with the mindset of "we live in a sensitive world", I'm sorry to break the bad news, you ARE a liability because you're pushing the issue on others. It is good that you realize that you made a mistake and you didn't intend to offend anyone but it is still YOUR responsibility. Every time somebody says they only had "good intentions", my first comment is "You know what they say about the road to hell, right?". You're expected to apologize and do not make the same mistake again. Some comments are not appropriate for a workplace and are best left for a social environment.

Answer (score 5):

How does it even come up?  I wouldn't mention it.   You can say you were let go because of a personality conflict with management, or difference of philosophy.

Having said that, explain you've learned since then, and have grown as a result.

Comment: We were just talking one day and i complimented her. It wasnt anything malicious or intentionally to harass. I just assumed that since she and i have a good foundation of mutual respect and trust, i can talk to her freely. What i didnt realized was that i was wrong. I mean, she was someone who really understood me as a person and we got along really well. I had no idea things would turn out like this.

Comment: @Lfhelpxyz do you compliment your male co-workers in the same way? No?  But it's past now, you've learned, and being able to see your male and female co-workers as just co-workers is a valuable skill to have.  Beating yourself up about the past isn't as fruitful as changing your future.

Comment: @Lfhelpxyz -- no, I mean, how does it come up in an interview?   How do they now to even ask about it?   Do you have a police record?   Does it come up on a  background check?  If not, don't tell them.    It sounds like you committed no crime, and there is no reason to volunteer to anyone that it happened.

Comment: Im doing my best to be positive. Would you think if i say i was let go due to personality conflict, would that be appropriate or would i be lying? I would go with misunderstanding but im not sure if i will be asked for details. Then i wouldnt know what to say. @thursdaysgeek

Comment: @keith i was NOT convicted of any crime. I would think it would come up when i was asked why did you leave your last job? I would obviously let the interviewer know that i got terminated (no problem owning that up). Then i would think interviewer would press for more details..? Furthermore, i was told that my previous employer will release the date of employment, title, and can i be rehired. And that reason for termination is strictly confidential. At least thats what i was told during exit interview. But im still afraid that they might release the reason as well..?